# Retrieving storage volume info from tree URI

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm adapting an application to Android, that allows backup to external storage (USB pen drives).

I'm currently using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to get the tree Uri to the selected provider.

```
public void chooseDrive(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

I get the URI, can create files, etc, but what I need is some way to programmatically identify the chosen provider, or, in other words, I want the info of the Usb device/Storage Volume, as it shows on the selection window, like the description and the size.

I should refer that minimal API is 19, so many TreeUri methods (Like DocumentFile.fromTreeUri, or DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree) are unusable.

Comment: "I should refer that minimal API is 19" -- `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` does not exist on API Level 19. That action was added in API Level 21. There are no tree `Uri` options for API Level 19, only document ones. "I want the info of the Usb device/Storage Volume, as it shows on the selection window, like the description and the size" -- I do not believe that there is way to get that.

Comment: My bad, I missed that detail. What could be the solution for Api's 19 and 20? ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT with mime-type dir?

Comment: "What could be the solution for Api's 19 and 20?" -- stick with `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural), where the second and subsequent entries point to a private location on removable storage that you can use. Note that API Level 20 was only for the first-generation Android Wear devices and so may not matter for you. "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT with mime-type dir?" -- there is no "dir" MIME type.

Comment: Actually there is: `DocumentsContract.Document.MIME_TYPE_DIR` @CommonsWare. In use at creating directories. Never tried it with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: @greenapps: OK, thanks!

Comment: Thank you, both.  @CommonsWare: Actually I have a device that lists the USB devices on ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE but doesn't list them on getExternalFilesDirs(), the reason why I ruled it out. That device uses Android 5.1.1. (API 22)

Comment: " Actually I have a device that lists the USB devices on ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE but doesn't list them on getExternalFilesDirs()" -- that's bizarre. What device is this?

Comment: O ive such a one too. An Android 6.0 Elephone P9000.  An OTG USB drive is accessible with SAF. But not mentioned in getExternalFilesDirs() which does mention the SD card. And also not mentioned under /storage. Also ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED is not invoked on this one.

Comment: In my case is a Wintec IDT800. I'll give ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT a try, and see if it can work out. Still, I have the same problem regarding the volume info. I can get the list of mounted volumes, through getVolumeList method of the mount service, but there no direct relation with the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, and I don't know if I can trust the apparent relation between a volume's Uid and the URI returned by the SAF's picker.

Comment: @NunoV. did u find a solution how to get Volume info from SAF's selected folder? For example I need to get free storage of the volume where users select folder for the app to work with

Answer (score 0):

```
StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
String treeDocumentId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri);
Uri documentUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(treeUri, treeDocumentId);
Uri mediaUri = MediaStore.getMediaUri(context, documentUri );
StorageVolume storageVolume = storageManager.getStorageVolume(mediaUri);
```

It's so trivial and obvious, I can't believe you asked.  :P

So, I know that's a convoluted mess and it requires API 29.  I feel like there has got to be an easier way, but it's the only thing I could figure out.

If you can't rely on API 29, you can parse the treeDocumentId.  For the device storage it's "primary:<dir>".  For everything else it is "<UUID>:<dir>" were UUID should equal StorageVolume.getUUID().  This is observational and not guaranteed by the APIs.  Also, the ":<dir>" suffix is optional.